# Nested callback is too deep

Tags: java, android

How to replace nested callbacks (Testing.java) for easy reading like this:

```
if(isValidGenderID() && isValidReligionID() && isValidMaritalID()){
   // DO PRIMARY TASK
}
```

Nested callbacks are too deep, making the program not easy to read!. How to resolved this problem?

//PersonValidation.java

```
public static void isValidGenderID(@NonNull Context context, int genderID, final IGenderDataSource.IIsExistGenderIDCallback callback) {

    GenderDataSource.getInstance(context).isExistGenderID(genderID, new IGenderDataSource.IIsExistGenderIDCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
            callback.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String result) {
            callback.onFailure(result);
        }
    });
}

public static void isValidReligionID(@NonNull Context context, int religionID, final IReligionDataSource.IIsExistReligionIDCallback callback) {
        ReligionDataSource.getInstance(context).isExistReligionID(religionID, new IReligionDataSource.IIsExistReligionIDCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
            callback.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String result) {
            callback.onFailure(result);
        }
    });
}

public static void isValidMaritalID(@NonNull Context context, int maritalID, final IMaritalDataSource.IIsExistMaritalIDCallback callback) {
        MaritalDataSource.getInstance(context).isExistMaritalID(maritalID, new IMaritalDataSource.IIsExistMaritalIDCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
            callback.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String result) {
            callback.onFailure(result);
        }
    });
}
```

// GenderDataSource.java

```
@Override
public void isExistGenderID(final int ID, @NonNull final IIsExistGenderIDCallback callback) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            db.sqlRawQuery();
            callback.onSuccess();
        }
    };
    appExecutors.getLocalDb().execute(r);
}
```

// ReligionDataSource.java

```
@Override
public void isExistReligionID(final int ID, @NonNull final IIsExistReligionIDCallback callback) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            db.sqlRawQuery();
            callback.onSuccess();
        }
    };
    appExecutors.getLocalDb().execute(r);
}
```

// MaritalDataSource.java

```
@Override
public void isExistMaritalID(final int ID, @NonNull final IIsExistMaritalIDCallback callback) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            db.sqlRawQuery();
            callback.onSuccess();

        }
    };
    appExecutors.getLocalDb().execute(r);
}
```

// Testing.java (Nested calls are too deep, making the program not easy to read)

```
@Override
public void createCustomer(@NonNull final Customer customer, @NonNull final ICustomerDataSource.ICreateCustomerCallback callback) {
    //
    // isValidGenderID?
    //                        
    isValidGenderID(context, customer.getGenderID(), new IGenderDataSource.IIsExistGenderIDCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
            if (result) {
                //
                // isValidReligionID?
                //
                isValidReligionID(context, customer.getReligionID(), new IReligionDataSource.IIsExistReligionIDCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
                        if (result) {
                            //
                            // isValidMaritalID?
                            //
                            isValidMaritalID(context, customer.getMaritalID(), new IMaritalDataSource.IIsExistMaritalIDCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
                                    if (result) {
                                        //
                                        // DO PRIMARY TASK
                                        //
                                    } else {
                                        callback.onFailure("Marital is not valid");
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(String result) {
                                    callback.onFailure(result);
                                }
                            });
                            //
                        } else {
                            callback.onFailure("Religion is not valid!");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String result) {
                        callback.onFailure(result);
                    }
                });
                //
            } else {
                callback.onFailure("Gender is not valid!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String result) {
            callback.onFailure(result);
        }
    });
}
```